# Setup an Elastic/Static IP in AWS to point to an Elastic Load Balancer for A Record

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

My website is setup on ECS behind a load balancer. I want my A Record to point to the load balancer, but Elastic Load Balancer's can't have static/elastic IP's assigned to them.

The DNS of a load balancer may be something like `my-loadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com` , and you can point a CNAME to it but not an A Record.

(We need an A Record to make MX records work properly, otherwise I would just use a CNAME).

Our domain name is hosted outside of AWS (i.e. not on Route53).

A very clunky and non-scalable way to handle this would be to setup a webserver (NGINX, IIS, etc) with an Elastic IP and simply have that redirect to the www version of my site, which uses a CNAME to point to the load balancer.

This is something I really want to avoid, for maintainability reasons and for scalability.

What is the quickest and most straight forward way to either point an A record to an ELB, or re-route an income request from an IP (mysite.com) to something else (www.mysite.com).

*Extra*
Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832260/ahost-records-with-aws-load-balancer), but dated. One answer say's it's not possible, and the other answer seems dated, and I don't believe is relevant.

Comment: But how is ELB related to MX records?

Comment: @DusanBajic because with no A Record, MX doesn't work. (And I can't use an A Record on a non-ip address)

Comment: Your mail server is behind ELB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your domain name hosted in Route 53 in order to have an A record pointing to the ELB.

[Here](http://%20https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/)'s a blog post on how to use a static ip in application load balancer, but its not very straight forward.

You could also have a look at the classic load balancer, prett ysure that you can use elastic IPs with that one.